# Why is my bubble sort not working? Java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

First time posting!
I have an assignment due that requires me to write a java program that reads in data from a text file and sorts it according to score and their initials.
The text file is as follows:

```
John Doe 75
Joe Blow 65
Mary Smith 80
John Green 82
Jill White 97
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String[] firstName = new String[5];
    String[] lastName = new String[5];
    int score[] = new int[5];
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("data.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int c=0;
        while(input.hasNext()){
            firstName[c] = input.next();
            lastName[c] = input.next();
            score[c] = input.nextInt();
            c++;
        }
        input.close();

    MichaelBubbleSort(score);
    for(int x=4;x>=0;x--){
        System.out.print(firstName[x].substring(0,1) + lastName[x].substring(0,1) + " " + score[x]);
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static void MichaelBubbleSort(int[] arr){
    int temp;
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++){

        for(int j=1; j < arr.length-i; j++){
            if(arr[j-1] > arr[j]){
                temp=arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

}

But for some reason it always comes out as:

```
JW 97                                                                                                                                                            
JG 82                                                                                                                                                            
MS 80                                                                                                                                                            
JB 75                                                                                                                                                            
JD 65
```

The output should be:

```
JW 97
JG 82
MS 80
JD 75
JB 65
```

Any reasons why this keeps happening?

Comment: you have sorted score but not sorted name accordingly. That's why you are facing this issue.

Comment: Which output would you expect? (please edit question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solution as per your code. but code must be better then this. you should use collection classes.
In this code you need to swap names accordingly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] firstName = new String[5];
        String[] lastName = new String[5];
        int score[] = new int[5];
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("D:\\test.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

        int c = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            firstName[c] = input.next();
            lastName[c] = input.next();
            score[c] = input.nextInt();
            c++;
        }
        input.close();

        MichaelBubbleSort(score,firstName,lastName);
        for (int x = 4; x >= 0; x--) {
            System.out.print(firstName[x].substring(0, 1)
                    + lastName[x].substring(0, 1) + " " + score[x]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void MichaelBubbleSort(int[] arr,String[] firstName, String[] lastName) {
        int temp;
        String tempFirstName,tempLastName;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
                if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                    temp = arr[j - 1];
                    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;

                    tempFirstName = firstName[j -1];
                    firstName[j - 1] = firstName[j];
                    firstName[j] = tempFirstName;

                    tempLastName = lastName[j -1];
                    lastName[j - 1] = lastName[j];
                    lastName[j] = tempLastName;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking that the sort would have taken care of the first and last name as well. And we aren't allowed to use collections because they aren't in the chapters that we are in right now. Thanks for the tip though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you don't sort the names according to the score. I would recommend to use object array to store data and then sort object array with bubble sort like this:

```
public class B{

public static void MichaelBubbleSort(Person[] arr){
    Person temp;
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length-1; i++){

        for(int j=1; j < arr.length-i; j++){
            if(arr[j-1].score > arr[j].score){
                temp=arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String x[]){
    Person [] a={new Person("John","Doe",75),new Person("Joe","Blow",65),new Person("Mary","Smith",80),new Person("John","Green", 82),new Person("Jill","White", 97)};
    MichaelBubbleSort(a);

    for(Person i:a){
        System.out.println(i.FirstName+" "+i.LastName+" "+i.score);
    }

}
}
```

Object class to hold data

```
class Person{
    int score;
    String FirstName;
    String LastName;

    Person(String FName,String LName,int Score){
        this.score=Score;
        this.FirstName=FName;
        this.LastName=LName;
    }
}
```